# The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:51218/session timed out after 60 seconds

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, azure-pipelines

I'm running this test setup on an azure devops pipeline and it continuously fails with a timeout.

Stack trace:

```
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
> commandToExecute)    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
> commandToExecute)    at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String
> driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities
> desiredCapabilities)    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor,
> ICapabilities capabilities)    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService
> service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service,
> ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String
> chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
> at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(String
> chromeDriverDirectory, ChromeOptions options)    at
> Selenium.WebDriverFactory.GetChromeDriver(TimeSpan
> webDriverTimeoutImplicitWait, String driverFolder, Boolean
> runHeadless)    at
> Selenium.WebDriverFactory.CreateLocalWebDriver(TimeSpan
> webDriverTimeoutImplicitWait, WebDriverType webDriverType, String
> driverFolder, Boolean runHeadless)    at
> Selenium.WebDriverFactory.Create(IEnumerable`1
> listOfSeleniumEndpointUrls, TimeSpan webDriverTimeoutImplicitWait,
> WebDriverType webDriverType, Boolean isLocalRun, Boolean runHeadless,
> String driverFolder, IDictionary`2 desiredCapabilities)    at
> Selenium.Base.TestBase.TestInitialize()
> --TaskCanceledException    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)   
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<MakeHttpRequest>d__35.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)   
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()    at
> OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
> commandToExecute)
```

I've upgraded chrome driver to 115.x and chromium to 115.x, upgraded selenium.wedriver to 4.11.0 and still seeing the same error Anyone able to see issues with our setup?